# How to fill column based on columns of another table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1

```
Name Cluster Centroid
Ann    1        (1,2)
Josh   2         (3,4)
Drake  3         (5,6)
```

and another dataframe df2

```
Name
Ann
Josh
Drake
Ann
Drake
nan    
Josh
```

How do I make cluster and centroid columns in df2 based on matching names in df1, accounting for nan? without iterating

So I want df2:

```
Name    Cluster   Centroid
Ann      1          (1,2)
Josh     2          (3,4)
Drake    3          (5,6)
Ann      1          (1,2)
Drake    3          (5,6)
nan      nan        nan
Josh     2          (3,4)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want merge in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)